# User does not have a profile on main site and can't be super-pinged

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, super-ping

I'm trying to ping [this user on SU](https://superuser.com/users/139604/kalina).

I write:

> @@139604@superuser.com Thanks for your retagging efforts. (…)

[image]

I get:

> kalina does not have a profile on superuser.com

Well duh:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Hey, I'm infamous already!

Comment: Worked for me in the sandbox

Comment: Maybe it was related to server cache problem causing 0 users on Stack Overflow? Good chance it's now working fine.

Comment: still reproducible?

Comment: @Braiam No idea… the user is deleted.